# Create a Custom ID in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-data-macro

I would like to create a Custom ID in format, "SACYear-Sequential Number", in an Access 2013 Table (Table Name = poledata) when records are appended into that Table.

eg. SAC18-1 (18 means 2018)

I have researched and found the code as below. As advised, I have to add 2 new fields in the Table, alternate_id_seq and alternate_id. However, errors show up for the following lines.

Expression = "SAC" & Year(Date()) Mod 100 & "-"

Look Up A Record In

```
Select pd.[alternate_id_seq] 
FROM poledata AS pd 
ORDER BY pd.[alternate_id_seq] DESC;
```

What's going wrong with them?

[image: image description]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Spent 30 minutes trying to get various DataMacros to set the value in a field with no success. So easy in VBA behind a form. Are you editing directly in table?

Comment: I finally got the SetField action to work when I included the table name in the field reference. In your case that would be like `poledata.alternate_id_seq`. But if you aren't even getting that far in code execution, that won't fix issue. As already requested, provide error messages.